# Haskell function to check permutation

Tags: function, haskell, boolean, permutation

If I declare data constructors such as

```
data City = Baltimore | Chicago | Seattle | Miami | Toronto
        deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

data Name = Orioles | Cubs | Mariners | Marlins | BlueJays
        deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)
```

How can I make a function

```
checkPermutation :: (City -> Name) -> Bool
```

to check that no two cities are assigned the same team name. For example, the following would return True but if any "Name" is assigned to more than one city it would return False.

```
test1 :: City -> Name
test1 c = case c of
    Baltimore  -> Orioles
    Chicago    -> Cubs
    Seattle    -> Mariners
    Miami      -> Marlins
    Toronto    -> Blue Jays
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```hs
import Data.List (nub)

cities :: [City]
cities = [Baltimore..Toronto]

checkPermutation :: (City -> Name) -> Bool
checkPermutation f = (== length cities) . length . nub . map f $ cities
```

This basically checks whether the function `f :: City -> Name` is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

In fact, we can create a more general `injective` predicate:

```hs
import Data.Set as Set

typeSet :: (Bounded a, Enum a, Ord a) => Set a
typeSet = fromList $ enumFrom minBound

injective :: (Enum a, Bounded a, Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Bool
injective f = let xs = typeSet in (== size xs) . size . Set.map f $ xs
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: And you can make this more efficient (if that's a concern) by adding an `Ord` constraint and using sets instead of `nub`.

Comment: Would I need to put that
"checkPermutation f = (== length cities) . length . nub . map f $ cities" in an if statement somehow so I can return either true or false?

Also, ghci isn't liking the "cities = [Baltimore..Toronto]", saying section must be enclosed by parentheses, and not in scope

Comment: @user2988976 No, the `(== length cities)` function itself returns a boolean. Also, you need to type `let cities = [Baltimore..Toronto]` if you're using GHCi.